# PBKDF2 password storage - how to validate?

Tags: php, passwords, salt, pbkdf2

I am trying to figure out how to validate the password, during login, when using PBKDF2. I am using PHP, so here is a basic password generation code:

```
$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
echo hash_pbkdf2('sha256', 'password', $salt, 1000, 32);
```

I have stored this hashed password in the database. I don't know how to test this password against a login input since I don't have the salt and the salt is generated randomly for each user. How can I "extract" the salt from the stored password, prepend it to the inputted password and test the result against the stored password?

Comment: Can't you just use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)? If you are not on PHP 5.5 there is an [equivalent implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) that you can use with any version >= 5.3.7.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know if this existed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the salt together with the hash, for example:

```
$hash = $salt . '|' . hash_pbkdf2(.., .., $salt, ..);
```

You can then later extract the salt from it again and feed it back into the validation algorithm. In fact, you should do this with all the relevant input parameters for the hash (except for the password itself, obviously), to allow you to change your algorithm later as needed while still being able to validate already hashed passwords:

```
$hash = $algo . '|' . $salt . '|' . $rounds . '|' . hash_pbkdf2($algo, .., $salt, $rounds, ..);
```

In fact, you should use the [`crypt`](http://php.net/crypt) API, which already does it like this.

But really, you should be using [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash), which is a user-friendly wrapper around `crypt` which ensures that you do it right.

Comment: I understand this completely but there is one thing that I just don't get in this system... What's the point of using salt if we are exposing it by pretending it to the hash?

Comment: The point of a salt is not to be secret, it's only to make the hash unique.

Comment: Hi, @deceze, I'm also wondering how I could implement this type of password hashing into a web application I am building however it hasn't received any input as of yet, care to take a look? The above comment seems to be an almost perfect solution to my question, I'm just not sure why it won't output as expected.